# Which JDK do Spring Data modules need to run?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

My application will be running in a Java 7 JVM. What is the most recent version of Spring-Data-JPA that is compatible with Java 7? Can't find it [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa) or [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/).

Comment: I suppose the newest one should be compatible. I do not know any popular framework/library/tool which is only for Java 1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general baseline of Spring Data modules is JDK 6. However, some of the modules (e.g. Neo4j) required a JDK 7 due to the fact that the store's Java driver already requires JDK 7.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `Spring-Data-Jpa 1.8.0` and my application is running ina Java 7 JVM.

If you check the [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.1.RELEASE/reference/html/) for the newest version `1.8.1`, you will see that some new features has been added in the favour of `java-8` (like the use of `Stream` but `java-7` is still supported.